# JMETER - WebDriver Sampler - Groovy - Dynamic Name

Tags: groovy, jmeter, jmeter-plugins

Can you please advise how to rewrite the below code with contains syntax for Dynamic Name? Please refer the attached screen capture. Thanks a lot.

WDS.browser.findElement(org.openqa.selenium.By.xpath("//li[@id='cascader-menu-9503-0-3']/span")).click();
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fail to see any element having id of `cascader-menu-9503-0-3` at your screenshot, if you want to click this "Location" dropdown it's better to stick to its `valuesdatasource` [attribute](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_attributes.asp) like:

```
//div[@valuesdatasource='location']
```

The general syntax for the [contains() function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/XPath/Functions/contains) is:

```
contains('target', 'criteria')
```

so in your case it would be something like:

```
//li[contains(@id, '9503')]
```

or

```
//li[contains(@id, 'cascader-menu')]
```

References:

- [XPath Tutorial](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xpath_intro.asp)
- [XPath Language Specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xpath-19991116/)
- [Using the XPath Extractor in JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/using-xpath-extractor-jmeter-0)